# Vis.js - how to hide the gridlines

Tags: aurelia, vis.js

**Tech Details:**

JS Framework: Aurelia

Charting Framework : vis.js (graph2D Library)

I am working on a grid layout for a dashboard view on a Aurelia based web site. The individual grids will display a small graph in the middle. 
Since I need only a basic line graph, I am using the Graph2D library.

After a few tries could get it to display the graph but it shows up with the grid lines and labels in the back, which in the small sized grid, looks hideous.

1) Can someone share the code piece to disable the gridlines and labels from showing..
my current option settings are:

```
    var options= {
    start : '2014-06-11',
    end : '2014-06-16',
    graphHeight: '45px',
    dataAxis:{
       showMinorLabels:false,
       showMajorLabels:false,
       visible:false
     }
    }
```

2) Also, my current item array is as follows (infact, I am using the one in the example) :

```
    var items = [
        {x: '2014-06-13', y: 30},
        {x: '2014-06-14', y: 10},
        {x: '2014-06-15', y: 15},
        {x: '2014-06-16', y: 30},
        {x: '2014-06-17', y: 10},
        {x: '2014-06-18', y: 15}
     ];
```

When I tried changing the "x:" values to something else (to display the time in my case ) like

```
    var items = [
        {x: '10:00', y: 30},
        {x: '10:30', y: 10},
        {x: '11:00', y: 15},
        {x: '11:30', y: 30},
        {x: '12:00', y: 10},
        {x: '12:30', y: 15}
        {x: '13:00', y: 30},
        {x: '13:30', y: 10}
    ];
```

It threw a 'X is NaN' error..
How can i change the values.. i have seen some suggestions of using a formatter..

Detailed code:

---

```
    import {BindingSignaler} from 'aurelia-templating-resource'
    import * as vis from 'vis'
    import * as _ from loadash 

    export class GraphDisplay{
     @bindable data : any;
     private graph= vis.Graph2D;
     private container = HTMLElement;

     attached()
      {
         this.drawGraph();
      }

     activate()
      {
       this.drawGraph();
      }

     private drawGraph()
     {
        if(!this.data)
        {
          return;
        }


      var items = [
             {x: '2014-06-13', y: 30},
             {x: '2014-06-14', y: 10},
             {x: '2014-06-15', y: 15},
             {x: '2014-06-16', y: 30},
             {x: '2014-06-17', y: 10},
             {x: '2014-06-18', y: 15}
           ];

       var dataset = new vis.Dataset(items);

       var options= {
            start : '2014-06-11',
            end : '2014-06-16',
            graphHeight: '45px',
            dataAxis:{
               showMinorLabels:false,
               showMajorLabels:false,
               visible:false
               }
         }

       if(this.container)
         {
           this.graph = new vis.Graph2D(this.container, dataset, groups, options);
         }
     else
         {
           console.log('No container found');
         }

      }

   }
```

---

The HTMLElement is bound through the ref attribute in the view

```
        <template>
           <div class="containerClass" id="graphContainer" ref="container" style="height:200px; width:200px;">
        </template>
```

Comment: Maxx, if possible, can you add more details or provide example code in `plunker`, `jsfiddle`, or in `codepen`? Check this https://plnkr.co/edit/agDy37or5U99OkhE link on how to implement aurelia project in `plunker`.

Comment: Which Vis component exactly are you talking about? Timeline?

Comment: @Joao Menighin:  Graph2D library, basic line graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To hide the grid use CSS:

```
.vis-background {
  display: none;
}
```

2) To hide time axis move the options `showMajorLabels` and `showMinorLabels` to the upper level:

```
var options = {
  start: '2014-06-13 09:30',
  end: '2014-06-13 13:00',
  graphHeight: '45px',
  dataAxis: {
    visible: false
  },
  showMajorLabels: false,
  showMinorLabels: false
};
```

3) You can specify the minutes in the data:

```
var items = [{
    x: '2014-06-13 10:00',
    y: 30
  }, ...
```

Complete example: https://jsfiddle.net/atnnL13f/

Comment: Thanks a bunch @stdob, the code solved 95% of my issues bout the display. Couple of small requests.. 
1. I still see a thin rectangular border around the graph. Anyway to get rid of that? 
2. Do you know how to change the color of the line and the icons?

Comment: @MaxxD If you want to hide border set border to `.vis-timeline`: https://jsfiddle.net/zrqst0oe/ ; Example to change color: http://visjs.org/docs/graph2d/#Styles

Comment: @stbob--: thanks for another fantastic suggestion.. I added the css that you provided to hide the gridlines. Then I used the dev tools to inspect the css for the lines and added the following:
`code`
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
.vis-graph-group0{
    fill: lime;    
    stroke-width: 3px;
    stroke: aqua;
    fill-opacity: 0;

}

.vis-timeline .vis-fill {
    fill-opacity: 0.1; 
    /* stroke: none;*/
}
`code`

Comment: I see that there is a small problem, the items do not achieve the same effects similar to the ones when changed in the dev tool. There is a light shaded area which appears here which is not there when done in the dev tools..also the icon color is changing with the change of the fill attribute, whereas it doesnt have any effect when added to the project any idea?

Comment: You can exclude the class of points from the selector: `.vis-graph-group0:not(.vis-point) {
  fill: lime;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke: aqua;
  fill-opacity: 0;
}` - https://jsfiddle.net/x6mb8eL3/

Comment: `2) To hide time axis move the options showMajorLabels and showMinorLabels to the upper level`


That's not in the manual, useful